# Resharper always puts tests as inconclusive or aborted

Tags: c#, resharper, xunit

I have VS 15.3.4 and ReSharper 2017.2.1 
Whenever I try to run xunit test it shows after run "Inconclusive: Test not run" or "Aborted". Same tests run in VS TestExplorer just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start Visual Studio in logging mode:

```
devenv.exe /ReSharper.LogFile C:\temp\resharper.log /ReSharper.LogLevel Verbose
```

If your log file contains “System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime”, then you have to exit Visual Studio and to change Windows datetime format in control panel to US and try again. If tests run fine, then you can switch dateformat back.

This is kind of similar problem described here: https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206702965-Cannot-get-Resharper-to-work-with-VS-2015

Comment: To me it came out as a windows problem. It seems that windows messed up Estonian locale for a while with one of the updates. But the fix was not activated on my PC. If I fixed it manually it was all OK again.

Answer (score 0):

Well some additional information would be great.
But I had this problem one time myself in a testclass with over 30,000 lines of code - so my solution was to "Disable Analysis" for this file.
You can do this by right clicking at the top of the scrollbar on the right.
There should be some Symbol, like a blue circle or a green button - if it´s disabled you see a circle with "II" in it.

Edit:
Make sure to have an open Test Session Window, because the "Run" symbols on the left side will disappear.

Comment: They aren´t disabled - just make sure to have an open Unit Test Session and you can run them. (But fair point - the launch symbols disappear in the class)